# Apache - how to define an exception with REMOTE_HOST?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-401

```
Require not ip
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR}
```

do not work reliable in my .htaccess.

This seems to lock out unwanted visitors better:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (sta\.81\.106\.9\.x\.client\.server\.de) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (sta\.83\.94\.46\.xx\.client\.server\.de) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (sta\.106\.51\.63\.xxx\.client\.server\.de) [NC,OR]
#...and more of these guys ...
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

But I do not want to lock out this:

sta.106.51.64.yyy.client.server.de  (corresponding to ip IP 88.198.yy.zzz)

How can I define this exception in my .htaccess ?

Comment: Do you have range of IPs OR anything common in names of hosts? Then only we can try to write them in regex or in shortcut, if that is the ask here.

Comment: Oh, I forgot it:
I want to lock out the bad guys by
RewritCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (\.client\.server\.de)
as a "group".
They have IP ranges, but RewritCond percent{remote_addr} does not satisfy.
In this comment, I garble the code intentionelly for secure reasons.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by `But I do not want to lock out this` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following htacces rules. We can put combine conditions and then accordingly block the requests from users.

You could check logs after applying these to see how system is behaving too.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?.*\.client\.server\.de$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www\.)?sta\.106\.51\.64\.yyy\.client\.server\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: ++ Wouldn't seem to be any need for the optional `(?:www\.)?` prefix?

Comment: @MrWhite, Thank you sir. Yeah I just added for safer side. Let me know if you want me to remove it? Its just optional and for safer side I kept it.

Comment: @josefus, Hi, could you please do let me know if these rules have helped you?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused when I wrote the first text.
Your condition helped me in a simpler matter:
`RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^(static\.)?.*\.clients\.server\.de$ [NC]`
and I don`t need the exception because the host that I do not lock out is like this:
'www123.clients-server.de'
Thank you for your support.

Comment: It helped only for some days.
The problem exists further more.
I think the .htacess rules are not quite sure.

Comment: @josefus, oh ok, request you to please do open new question and we could discuss it there, cheers.